# SQL query for getting few things from one table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with one table. This is how table looks:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+------+
| index_id | version_id |    date     | type |
+----------+------------+-------------+------+
|        1 |          4 | today       | C    |
|        1 |          2 | last month  | C    |
|        1 |          4 | today       | U    |
|        2 |          3 | yesterday   | c    |
|        2 |          4 | today       | C    |
|        2 |          2 | last year   | U    |
|        3 |          7 | yesterday   | C    |
|        3 |          6 | last month  | C    |
|        3 |          8 | today       | U    |
+----------+------------+-------------+------+
```

What I want to achieve is to get  indexes (index_id) with max version and max date of both types.

Like this:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+------+
| index_id | version_id |   date    | type |
+----------+------------+-----------+------+
|        1 |          4 | today     | C    |
|        1 |          4 | today     | U    |
|        2 |          4 | today     | C    |
|        2 |          3 | yesterday | U    |
|        3 |          7 | yesterday | C    |
|        3 |          8 | today     | U    |
+----------+------------+-----------+------+
```

I want to ask you for some ideas for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: "max version and max date" what does this mean? One, the other, a combination of both?

Comment: How do you get 2 | 3 | yesterday | U? It's not in the source. There is only 2 |          3 | yesterday | **c**.

Comment: Today isnt a date, at least isnt one for oracle

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by index_id, type order by version_id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number` and `partition` to get the max in each group for a given index_id and type combination

```
select index_id,version_id,date,type from 
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by index_id,type order by version_id,desc) as r_no
    from table
) a
where a.r_no = 1
```

Comment: Not fast enough to beat @Gordon-Linoff to the answer Sigh  :(

Comment: Once you partition by `index_id`, you dont need `order by index_id`. Because all the rows on the partition has the same id

Answer (score 0):

I would use `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where version_id = (select max(t1.version_id) 
                    from table t1 
                    where t1.index_id = t.index_id and 
                          t1.type = t.type 
                   );
```